# Closest divisible integer

Tags: java, math

Example.

```
int a = 254;
int b = 25;

int c = (closest integer to `a` that is divisible by `b`)
```

How can I find the integer `c`? The result of that example is `c = 250`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are two cases to consider:

1. The closest integer that is less than or equal to `a`:

   ```
   int c1 = a - (a % b);
   ```
2. The closest integer that is greater than `a`:

   ```
   int c2 = (a + b) - (a % b);
   ```

Then we need to check which is closer to `a` and return that:

```
int c;
if (a - c1 > c2 - a) {
    c = c2;
} else {
    c = c1;
}
```

So we could create a `closestInteger()` method like this:

```
static int closestInteger(int a, int b) {
    int c1 = a - (a % b);
    int c2 = (a + b) - (a % b);
    if (a - c1 > c2 - a) {
        return c2;
    } else {
        return c1;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(closestInteger(254, 25));
System.out.println(closestInteger(9, 5));
```

Output:

```
250
10
```

Comment: `int c2 = (a + b) - (a % b);` with `a=10` and `b=10` returns 20 instead of 10.

Comment: @Constantin, that's correct. As explained in case 2, `c2` is the closest integer that is greater than `a=10` and divisible by `b=10`, that's 20. In this case, `c1` will be 10. Later we check which one is closer to `a=10` and return it.

Answer (score 4):

You have to check on both sides of `a`. So we set 'c1' to the closest integer below (or equal to) `a`, and `c2` to be the closest integer above it. Then compare the differences. If `c1` is closer to `a`, set `c` to `c1`, otherwise `c2`.

```
int c1 = a - (a % b);
int c2 = c1 + b;
int c = a - c1 < c2 - a ? c1 : c2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Closest below:
int c = (a/b)*b;

Since a and b are both int.  The division a/b will truncate to the nearest in value (10). Then multiplying the result by b will give what you are looking for.

Or

Closest either way:

int c = Math.round((float)a/b))*b;

Since a is cast as float the answer will be a float and rounding goes to the nearest int.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind going to the next highest integer when there is a tie (e.g. closest integer to 6 that is a multiple of 4 becomes 8 and not 4), then you can use this simple formula.  No comparisons are needed.

```
int c = (a + b/2)/b * b;  // closest integer to `a` that is divisible by `b`
```

All calculations are done with integer arithmetic (fractions are discarded).

Comment: very simple, but id like to avoid the higher integer

Comment: What happens if `a = 1; b = 4;` ? Expected answer should be `4`.

Comment: @truthadjustr, the closest integer to 1 that is divisible by 4 is 0.  How do you get 4?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var nums = [0, 9, 26, 39];
for (var i=0 ; i<nums.length;i++){
    const mod = nums[i]%3;
    if(mod!=0){
        console.log("Closest Multiple: "+(3*Math.round(nums[i]/3)))
    }else{
        console.log("Closest multiple: "+nums[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void checkDivisibility(int i,int j) {
    int mod = i % j;
    if (mod == 0) {
        System.out.println(i+ " is divisible by 13 ");

    } else {
        if (mod >= 7) {
            i = (i + (j - mod));
        } else {
            i = i - mod;
        }
        System.out.println(i+" is the nearest divisible ");
    }
}
```

**Call this method : checkDivisibility(40,13);
Output           : 39 is the nearest divisible**

Answer (score 0):

- Closet number less than a
  int c1 = a - (a % b);
- Closet number greater than a
  int c2 = a + (b - (a%b))

Now compare which one has less difference from a

int d1 = a - c1;

int d2 = c2 - a;

if(d1 > d2)//closest number is c2

else //closest number is c1

Answer (score 0):

```
int actual; // for example 23
int divisibleBy; // for example 8
int result = actual + divisibleBy - 1 & -divisibleBy; // result is 24
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.